# Jupyter Notebook not launching, "ImportError: No module named six"

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am not able to launch Jupyter Notebook in my Python 2.7 environment. It was working yesterday, but now I'm getting an "ImportError: No module named six" message. When I check my conda list, six version 1.12.0 exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install --ignore-installed six
```

then try to launch it again